# Quarkus Mutiny Multi filter Exception handling

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

What is the proper way to handle exceptions in the filter method of a multi, since we can only return a boolean and can not propagate failure? This is how my code looks like right now, how should I handle the exception in the filter properly?

```
Multi multi = ...;//
multi.filter(data -> {
        try{
            return applyFilter(data);
        } catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("exception occurred while checking filter", e);
            //instead of returning false, how should I propagate the exception?
            return false;
        }
    }
).onItem().transform(data -> {
       return transformData(data);  
   }       
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `filter` predicate throws an exception, that exception is propagated downstream as a failure. If, in that case, you want to return `false`, you need to do as you did (`try/catch` and return `false`).

In the exception case, the predicate can only throw runtime exceptions. You can use the *unchecked* utility methods (https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/unchecked) if you want to throw a checked exception. It wraps the exception in a runtime exception for you.

Comment: Thank you @Clement